# How to run android project on android phones?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, avd-manager

I am working on an app written in kotlin right now it is very basic app, I want to run that app on my phone, I have enable USB debugging but still on android studio project I am unable to see my phone name? Any help. Thanks

[Android Studio Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdzzs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing your device in the "Choose Device" window? Try the following:

- Unplug your device from the USB port on the computer
- Restart the device by powering off and back on
  *Verify that
  Settings => Developer options => USB Debugging √ is enabled
- Quit and re-launch Android Studio
- Force restart ADB from the "Android Device Monitor"
- Plug your device back into the USB port on the computer

*** Unlock the device and press "OK" on any dialog displayed ***

You will receive an allow dialogue before accessing your phone.

Comment: I get the allow USB debugging option on my phone but when I click on allow it say "because an app is obscuring a permission request, settings can't verify your response"

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I just disabled gesture motion on my phone

Comment: Go to Settings -> Apps -> Special Access -> Draw Over Other Apps

See which apps have permission to draw over other apps, and turn them off one by one until the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the answer by another user. You should also check you have the USB driver installed. Install the Google USB driver in Android Studio First. Then try installing the application. Follow this tuturial [Get the Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) to learn how to do just that